# jQuery Editable / Sortable List

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I am looking for a jQuery list that is editable (add, change, delete elements), what is a good starting point code base that does this?

I found this one example which is great, but it doesn't add, edit or delete list items:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/default.html

Answer (score 0):

you would use that jQuery library along side some small plugins, there not that hard to extend if you understand the Dom and jQuery.

take a look at this plug-in for example.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html